# Geocode Data - How to Use .kml File in R

Tags: r, kml, r-leaflet

I've used some open source data to produce choropleth maps showing population density in the Republic of Ireland using the `leaflet` package in R.

Found a suitable `.kml` file which is based on the same geocodes as my table of population density (it's at "small area" level which splits up the country into about 19,000 chunks).

I have some code to import the `.kml` file:

```
ireland <- readOGR("Source Data/Small_Areas__Generalised_100m__OSi_National_Boundaries.kml")
```

and a data frame `df_merged` which has fields `GEOGID` and `density` (and a few others). The code for producing the map is:

```
popup1 <- paste0("<span style='color: #7f0000'><strong>Data</strong></span>",
                 "<br><span style='color: salmon;'><strong>Small Area: </strong></span>", df_merged$GEOGID, 
                 "<br><span style='color: salmon;'><strong>Population: </strong></span>", df_merged$T1_1AGETT,
                 "<br><span style='color: salmon;'><strong>Area: </strong></span>", df_merged$Shape__Area,
                 "<br><span style='color: salmon;'><strong>Density: </strong></span>", df_merged$density
)

mymap_density <- leaflet() %>%

  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas",
                   options = tileOptions(minZoom = 5,
                                         maxZoom = 18,
                                         opacity = 1)) %>%

  addPolygons(data = ireland,
              fillColor = ~palette_density(df_merged$density),
              fillOpacity = 0.5,
              color = "darkgrey",
              weight = 0.1,
              popup = popup1) %>%

  addLegend(position = "topleft",
            colors = my_color_scheme,
            labels = c("Lowest", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Highest"),
            opacity = 0.6,
            title = "Population Density")
```

The map draws fine, but there's a problem: it's fairly obvious that the data for a given geocode isn't appearing in the correct part of the map. For example, in the map below, the geocode A048053001 represents a small urban area in Cork but the data for this geocode is shown in a completely different place on the map. The map is telling me that a big empty area of countryside has a tiny area and an enormous population density, which is daft.

I don't really know anything about the innards of `.kml` files so I'm not sure how to go about fixing this problem. At no point in the code have I told R that the `df_merged$GEOGID` field should be associated with a particular polygon inside the `.kml` file - so have I missed out a stage or made a mistake here?

If I import the .kml file into Google Earth, this problem doesn't occur - which I think rules out any problems with the underlying data (which is supplied by the Irish government which ought to be a reliable source anyway).

The above code isn't really a reproducible example since it relies on external data files.

Can anyone offer any advice please?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: As you say yourself - this example isn't at all reproducible. You should definitely be linking your polygons to the attribute data you want to map or at least make sure the records are in the same order in both. Post a sample of your actual data or at least links to the datasets.

Comment: Fair point about the lack of reproducibility. I was in the middle of amending my code to show links to the datasets but I discovered that the problem was that the dataframe df_merged - which was created by doing a left join on two tables, one of which was ordered differently (it seems) to the .kml file - was what was messing things up. So I think I may have fixed the problem. Should I post an "I have answered my own question" response below? (I'm quite new to SO)

Comment: If the issue was something like ordering, a more robust method would be to left join your attribute data to the polygon file directly to avoid the possibility of that. Good that you found a solution though so feel free to answer yourself if you feel your answer might help someone else out looking for a similar thing

Comment: `kml` files are just xml-like text files, so you can open it in a text editor and have a look at what is going on.  I would guess that your problem is in the definition of `popup1` - perhaps the names used in `df_merged` are different from those in the `kml` file, so the popups are not matched with the correct polygons.  Without seeing the data it is hard to be more precise.

Comment: I insist too. You need to share your kml in order to tryout.